# Ошибка Iterator global flags must be a list or tuple of strings

Tags: python, numpy

Выходит вот такая ошибка при выполнения кода `Iterator global flags must be a list or tuple of strings`, не знаю как решить данную проблему, в БД у меня все значения заданы "varchar"
Вот код:

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

data_base = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
sql = data_base.cursor()
for row in np.nditer(sql.execute("""SELECT token, user_tg_id FROM users """), flags="REFS_OK"):
    print(row[1], row[0])
```

Comment: Ну там же написано - итератор ждёт флаги в виде списка или кортежа строк, наверное нужно написать так: `flags=["REFS_OK"]` или так `flags=("REFS_OK",)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Буквально ошибка переводится так: "глобальные флаги итератора должны быть списком или кортежем строк", т.е. вы должны передать флаги списком:

```
flags=["REFS_OK"]
```

Или кортежем:

```
flags=("REFS_OK",)
```

Answer (score 5):

Советую вам обратить внимание на модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data_base = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
df = pd.read_sql("""SELECT token, user_tg_id FROM users""", data_base)
print(df)
```

Comment: missing 1 required positional argument: 'con' выдает эту ошибку не понимаю в чем именно проблема

Comment: @Body, исправил ответ…